# Base class and drived pages load event

Tags: asp.net

My aspx pages pages are drived from a base class, my base class creates the dynamic header of my website. I have a method called "genMenu" and i call in within pageLoad event of base class to create menu. 
In some pages i need to override this method, however as we know page load of base class fires before the pageLoad of drived pages. So i cant really do that.

So how can i override the genMenu in aspx page and NoT fire it within base class.  I know i can manually call the genMenu function in all drived pages, and not call it within pageLoad of base class, but there has to be a better way of handling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a virtual method called `GenerateMenu` or something like that, and always call it from the base page. Do the actual work there. Then your derived pages that need to intercept it can override that instead.

E.g., something like this:

```
// Base page

protected SomeType MenuVariable;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.GenerateMenu();
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    this.GetMenuVariable();
}

private void GetMenuVariable() {
    // Some stuff with query string or the database
    this.MenuVariable = FooBar();
}

protected virtual void GenerateMenu() {
    // Generate the menu here 
}
```

And:

```
// Derived page

protected override void GenerateMenu() {
    // Calls from the base page Load event
    // will be intercepted by this override
    // Do the alternate work for this page
    // here
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, while you understand what i need, let me go further with this.... My genMethod expects a value, by default this property is pressent as a QueryString in url, but few pages dont have this querystring parameter present within url, in that case i get the value from database and want to feed it to genMenu function (which is within pageload of base class).

Comment: If that step does not involve anything related to the page or controls, you can isolate it and override `OnInit` in the base page, which happens before `Page_Load`. See the update I made to the sample. If you let the base page handle the menu stuff or it's overridden by a derived page, `MenuVariable` will be available.

Comment: Thanks, i was using "overridable" keyword in vb.net already, i thought virtual is something new  I was able to fix it by using Mybase.methodname for the pages where i needed the special requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on clarification:

In your base class, define a `virtual` method called `AutoCallGenMenu()`, which returns true by default.  In your page load in the base class, check the result of that method, if it returns true, call `genMenu()`.

In the pages you want to manually call `genMenu()`, override `AutoCallGenMenu()` to return false.  Then, just manually call the method where you need it.

Comment: Genmenu needs to be called on all pages, on few pages i need to change the menu and i prefer to call it within drived page rather then base pageload. In other words, by default it should fire in base class pageload event, only in few pages i need NOT to fire but fire it manually within drived page. Does virtual method solves the problem?

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `pageLoad`, why don't you use `pageInit` or `page_init` to call your method, so that it occurs before `page_load`?

Refer to the. Net page life cycle for order of execution, you can then decide which method is best to use

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx

I may have misunderstood your question, but tou could also override your genmenu and ignore thr call to `.base()`